# How to kill processing without ending rsession

Tags: r, session, rstudio, kill-process

I was wondering if in R there is a way/keyboard shortcut/command/processing-thread-killing-alternative. For instance, using RStudio as IDE, you got a little stop button to kill the current processing thread(s), but most of the times it ends up in the prompt to end the session and restart the environment. Suggestions?

Comment: Escape works for me (using R on OSX)...

Comment: If the underlying R session is not responding to a stop request, that could imply it's frozen, or stuck running non-interruptable code (e.g. C, C++ code). Unfortunately, there's not much you can do in that state beyond killing the R session.

Comment: Yes, that can very well happen. I mean more like if you launched a function for instance over a huge data frame and you realized you've made a wrong parameter setting and you do not want to wait 1 hour until it finishes in order to correct it. You would not want to quit the session either and lose time loading your objects again. From some functions it can get out, but for instance with the `apply` "family' it doesn't really work.

Comment: @lmo I already mentioned the stop button in my question. That is not the issue. Please read the question more carefully. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Did you find a satisfying answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + C  <- will stop the R process without exiting the R session

and not

Ctrl + Z  <- will stop the R process and exit the R session